# DataGridView comboBoxColumn dateTime format

Tags: c#, datagridview, string-formatting

Winform, dataGridview with a comboBox column. The column datasource is pointing to an Sql table "dateTime" field format. Each row contains a data like 01/01/2014, 01/02/2014, etc..  I am trying to format the comboBox cell in dataGridView to show only month/Year.

I tried directly in the designer with a custom format:

[image]

and with the code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Periodo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = ("{0:M/yyyy}");
```

and like this

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Periodo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "M/yyyy";
```

and in many other ways. I cannot get it right, the comboBox keeps showing 01/01/2014 type format. How can I format such column to get "January 2014", "February 2014", etc..?

Comment: How about `"MMM yyyy"` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül. Nope, still not changing anything, I tried this: dataGridView1.Columns["Periodo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MMM yyyy";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the format you tried (`"M/yyyy"` is fine) neither in the `Format` property not working. The problem is that what you did affects the cell contents, not the combobox contents.

The best way to avoid problems with `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`/`DataGridViewComboBoxCell` is dealing with the items of the combobox, rather with the cell itself. Sample code:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.Name = "DateCol";
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>() { DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1) };
//Dates = Dates.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
List<string> colSource = dates.Select(x => x.ToString("M/yyyy")).ToList(); 
col.DataSource = colSource;

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

In this code, I am dealing with the list of dates (and, eventually, ordering it or performing any other required action); but then I create a list of (properly-formatted) strings to be the combobox source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and explanation. After reading your answer I got the light.It works perfectly, I just changed the format to "MMM/yyyy" to get what I was looking for.